# Python: Compressing all the contents of a log file to a tgz format

Tags: python

I am supposed to compress this directory called "log" which contains various logs(almost 50 logs) from different devices. This is the code so far I have tried...

```
import tarfile
import os
import glob

def value():

    tar = tarfile.open("Archive.tgz","w:gz")
    path = '/var/log'
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    for name in glob.glob(path):
        tar.add(name, arcname = "log")
    tar.close()
    if os.path.isfile('./Archive.tgz'):
        print "Compressed Successfully !"
    else:
    print "File not Found!"

value()
```

I keep getting this error though:

```
File "tar2.py", line 18, in <module>
value()
File "tar2.py", line 11, in value
tar.add(name, arcname = "log")
File "../../../../../../../src/dist/python/Lib/tarfile.py", line 2002, in add
File "../../../../../../../src/dist/python/Lib/tarfile.py", line 1994, in add
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/cscript.log'
```

I read a lot about this error online and tried using chmod as well. But nothing works.
Please help me out!

Comment: Perhaps `cscript.log` is being used by another process? What does `fuser /var/log/cscript.log` return?

Comment: This seems rather unlikely. Both processes (Python and the other one) would have to use `fcntl` locking... which could get us `EACCES` if Python try to run `F_SETLK` to acquire a lock. I've just checked... Python does not seem to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error (`EACCES`) is propagated from the underlying OS (filesystem) and there isn't much you could do about it with your script. You need to either give (read) permission to the user running your script. Or you can run your script with another user that has sufficient rights on that file.

You mention having changed mode on the file, but could it be that access was still not granted to the effective user id under which the script runs? You can verify your current user id and groups it is member of by running `id` in shell. And for instance long listing of the file will tell you current mode setting (`ls -l /var/log/cscript.log`).

It can also happen. Even if you change the permission bits, the process writing this file can check and reset the, Or the file gets created anew with original mode/ownership information. And the process writing into it has been restarted.

Comment: Alright, I knew it somewhere just needed it confirmed from an expertise. Thank you

Comment: Is there any way "to not reset the ownership" while the process is writing this file which can be implemented in the script ?

Comment: If that is what happened, you'd have to check who writes and if... it could be configured not to... or modify the program itself. I guess the bottom line here is... some of the logs are considered sensitive and should really be made available to read from to the wider world. Hence I suspect using a privileged user for collecting them might be a reasonable course of action.

Comment: -rw-------  1 root  wheel  54676 Jul  3 10:48 /var/log/cscript.log This is the output when I run ls -l for /var/log/cscript.log/ Does this mean, I will have to ask a privileged user to run the script?

Comment: More specifically only `root` can do that (or another user with elevated privileges e.g. if your system can do so through `sudo`). As is owned by `root` and only `root` can read it.

Comment: Yes, it worked. I needed privileged access to make it work. Thanks for the help!